# Importing SCSS partials in Angular Dart

Tags: sass, dart, angular-dart

I am building a project with Angular Dart (My first serious one). I am familiar with SCSS and have used it in other 'normal' non-angular non-dart related projects. However, SCSS in AngularDart behaves way differently than I'm used to, and it's leaving me a little confused.

The thing I'm struggling with right now is how to import partials. In 'normal' scss I would do something like this to import `_mixins.scss`:

```
@import 'mixins';
```

In my angular dart project, I tried doing something similar. The mixin file I created was one directory up so I tried this:

```
@import '../mixins';
```

That didn't work. The exact error message was `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.`. So, I googled a bit and came up with this:

```
@import '/src/components/widgets/mixins';
```

No luck. It told me that `only "package" and "asset" schemes supported`. So I tried this:

```
@import 'package:dbClient/src/components/widgets/mixins';
```

And it proceeded to tell me `"package:" URLs aren't supported on this platform.` I've never seen an `asset` URL and am not sure what that even is, but I tried this anyway:

```
@import 'asset:dbClient/src/components/widgets/mixins';
```

Which brought me right back to `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.`

So, I did some more googling, and ended up moving my scss partial file from `lib/src/widgets/` to a new folder I called `lib/assets/scss/`. However, I still can't seem to figure out how to import it into my component's scss file.

To sum it up, how do you create an scss partial file an import it into a component's scss file? Also, where do you put it?

(Also tangentially related but less concerning at the moment, what would you recommend as the best way to create global rules that apply to all components?)

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dart-sass will follow package syntax and rules for imports. Partials definitely work you can see that here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/material_button/material_button.scss

The asset syntax never really took off and I think most of the tools probably don't support it at this time. Just put the assets into the lib alongside the other source code.

I'm not sure if dart-sass respects the src convention that it should not be imported using the package syntax. That might be part of the problem.

In terms of where to put globals. I tend to subscribe to the notion that you don't want to pollute the global space and so have common imports for common variables and mixins and use those in the components when needed. Understandably these can be a bit heavyweight for some, but I work on really big projects so not having global CSS messing with things saves us a lot of headaches. You can see that pattern in play here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/material_button/_mixins.scss

That said another strategy is you can have a regular scss/css file linked in the root html page that will have common selectors/styles that will apply everywhere. Since it is outside of the encapsulation space it will apply to everything that matches.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why the partial syntax wasn't working for me. Maybe I'll have to try it again... Thanks for explaining things and clearing it up for me though.

Answer (score 0):

No sure what is your problem here but:

Register Sass in pubspec.yaml like this in your `dev_dependencies:`:

`dev_dependencies:
      sass_builder: ^2.1.1`

Then, in your .scss file put this:

- @import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins';

Finally, in your component file add this, inside `@Component()` :

`styleUrls: const [
      'name_of_your.css',
    ])`

This is **.css** not **.scss**.

See for more informations

- https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

---

Update

include this line in your main `.scss` file:

`@import '_partial.scss';`

Then, in your `_partial.scss` file, precise `!important` after each property you **need to override**.

That should works, at least, it works for me as expected.

Comment: Actually, I have the main scss file for the component working fine already. What I'm trying to do is import an scss partial with a few mixins i have created into that scss file. The import statement in scss isn't behaving like in normal scss.

Comment: That certainly looks like it ought to work. Any logical human would look at that and say it should work. For some reason it isn't though. It claims it can't find the file even though I have quadruple-checked the file name is typed correctly.

I've even tried moving the partial to the same folder just temporally, just so I could ensure the issue doesn't have anything to do with too many `'../'`s.

Comment: Update: apparently it's choking up on the underscore in the filename. I removed that and now I am able to import files fine. This seems like it might be a bug to me, but at least I know.

Thanks for taking the time to try and help me!